# Autocorrelation function of Itô process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm working with a time independent (vector) Itô SDE such as:

$$
dX = a(X) dt + b(X) dW.
$$

I've looked (numerically) at several examples and it seems that the autocovariance function $r_{xx}(\Delta t)$ is continuous and goes to zero exponentially fast at large $\Delta t$.

Is that true for sufficiently nice $a$, $b$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\Cov{\operatorname{Cov}}\newcommand\De\Delta$No. Even in the nicest case when $a=0$ and $b=1$, so that $X=W$, we have
$$\Cov(X_t,X_{t+\De t})=t\underset{\De t\to\infty}{\not\longrightarrow}0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for any real $t\ge0$.

On the other hand, for any smooth enough $a$ and $b$ and any real $t\ge0$ and $\De_t\ge0$, the random variable $X_{t+\De t}-X_t$ is independent of $X_t$ (and even of the entire pre-history $(X_s\colon s\in[0,t])$), so that
$$\Cov(X_t,X_{t+\De t}-X_t)=0 \tag{2}\label{2}$$
and, moreover,
$$\Cov(X_s-X_r,X_{t+\De t}-X_t)=0 \tag{3}\label{3}$$
for all real $r,s$ in $[0,t]$.
Perhaps, this is the reason for your numerical observations. (The equalities in \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} also follow from the equality in \eqref{1}.)

---

N.B.: The correct way to write the SDE is this: $dX_t=a(X_t)\,dt+b(X_t)\,dW_t$.

Comment: Case $a=0$ looks quite special. For example in Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process covariance goes to zero fast. Maybe if $X$ has stationary distribution?

Comment: TeX note:  Although of course there is nothing wrong with `\newcommand\Cov{\operatorname{Cov}}`, there is a shortcut, namely, `\DeclareMathOperator\Cov{Cov}`.

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Radost : No, $a=0$ is not an exception. In particular, any drift not depending (or weakly enough depending) on $X_t$ will do, for the autocovariance not to go to $0$. Any drift of the form $a(x)=bx+c$ with $b\ge0$ will do as well. On the other hand, the case of stationary diffusion processes is indeed special. Since stationarity is not mentioned in your post, I suggest that you post the question with the additional stationarity condition separately, possibly elsewhere, making sure that the modified question does not look as a duplicate.

Comment: @Radost : Do you have a further response to this answer and the comments?

Comment: In the vector case equation 2 is not true anymore if you look at just one component. (A projection of vector Markov processes is not Markov anymore).

Comment: It turns out one dimensional processes with unbounded variance are just too different from what I'm studying to give significant insight.

Comment: I was hoping for some estimate of tail of $r_xx$, for example how much 0 to h integral of it (which I can numerically estimate) differs from true 0 to infinity integral.